# Using Selenium on Amazon

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium

I do not understand why selenium will not input my data into amazon search. I know it opens the chrome browser to amazon but it will not fill in the search bar. Any ideas whats wrong with my code

```js
from lxml import html, etree
import csv,os,json
import requests
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver



textsearch = "Taco Bell Sauce"

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/home/path/Documents/Selenium/chromedriver')
browser.get("http://www.amazon.com/")
content = browser.page_source

doc = html.fromstring(content)
search = selenium.find_element_by_id("twotabsearchtextbox")

search.send_keys(textsearch)

search.selenium.find_element_by_id("nav-search-submit-text").click()
```

Any corrections on how i can make this work

Answer (score 3):

This is simply because you should handle the WebDriver instance, that you've created - `browser` instead of `selenium` which is Python library that contains `webdriver`...

So just replace

```
search = selenium.find_element_by_id("twotabsearchtextbox")
```

with

```
search = browser.find_element_by_id("twotabsearchtextbox")
```

P.S. Also replace

```
search.selenium.find_element_by_id("nav-search-submit-text").click()
```

with

```
browser.find_element_by_id("nav-search-submit-text").click()
```

or

```
search.submit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a couple of adjustments in your code as follows:

The `webdriver` instance gets assigned to `browser` so while using `find_element` you need to use the `browser`. The `Search Box` and the `Search Button` are within input tag so better to construct an `xpath` or a `css_selector` as follows :

```
from lxml import html, etree
import csv,os,json
import requests
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

textsearch = "Taco Bell Sauce"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get("http://www.amazon.com/")
content = browser.page_source
doc = html.fromstring(content)
search = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']")
search.send_keys(textsearch)
search.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='nav-input']").click()
```